# Merge two rows with same information but in different columns into one

Tags: sql, join, union, dbeaver

Assuming I have a table containing the following information:

```
FK | Field1 | Field2
=====================
3  | ABC    | DEF
3  | DEF    | ABC
```

[image: TABLE 1]

I would like to merge these two rows into one.
Is there a way I can perform a select on the table to get the following:

```
FK | Field1 | Field2
=====================
3  | ABC    | DEF
```

[image: TABLE 2]

Comment: What is your logic for picking one row over the other? Why `ABC | DEF`  rather than `DEF | ABC`?

Comment: Also dbeaver is just an IDE. What is the DBMS (sql server, oracle, postgres, etc)? Update tags with the actual dbms.

Answer (score 0):

you can to cte and join for solve problem

first you select rows unique and first row of duplicate rows

second you select secend row of duplicate rows

finally you use inner join to remove duplicate and use left join rows unique

```
with firsts as(
        select  id,Field1,Field2  from (
                    select 
                                id
                               ,Field2
                               ,Field1
                               ,ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by id order by id) as RW
                    from #r
        )a
        where a.RW=1
), sec as(
 

select id,Field2 as Field1 ,Field1 as Field2   from (
            select 
                        id
                       ,Field2
                       ,Field1
                       ,ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by id order by id) as RW
            from #r
)a
where a.RW=2

)

select  a.id,a.Field1,a.Field2
from firsts a
inner join     sec b on 
a.Field1=b.Field1 
and a.Field2=b.Field2
and a.id=b.id

union 

select  a.id,a.Field1,a.Field2
from firsts a
left join     sec b on 
a.Field1=b.Field1 
and a.Field2=b.Field2
and a.id=b.id
where b.id is null
```

You can to insert the basic data with the following codes

```
create table #r(id int,Field1 nvarchar(100),Field2 nvarchar(100))

insert into #r
select 1,'AAA','BB' union select 2,'cc','dd' union select 3,'ABC','DEF'
union select 3,'DEF','ABC'
```